# Unknown gap between table td's

Tags: html, css, html-table

Quite simply, I have a black line showing between two `td` elements and I'm not sure why.

I've tried `valign="bottom"` and `valign="top"` accordingly in an attempt to move the `td` in the gap but then the td sizes vary.

```html
<table bgcolor="#0a1219" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:692px;background-color:#0a1219;" width="692">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!------------->
      <!-- IMAGE 1 -->
      <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;;padding-left:20px; max-height: 286px; max-width:332px;" valign="bottom">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <!-- IMAGE -->
              <td align="right" style="font-family:'Arial',Helvetica,sans-serif;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img alt="Image-1" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/image-1.png" style="display:block;border:0px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#ffffff" height="286">
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <!------------->
      <!-- IMAGE 2 -->
      <td align="left" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;padding-right:20px; max-height: 286px; max-width:332px;" valign="bottom">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <!--ROW 1 IMAGE -->
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; background-color:#00adf2;">

                <img alt="Speech marks" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/speech.png" style="display:block;border:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#ffffff; padding-top: 3px;" width="310">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!--ROW 1 TEXT -->
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="background-color:#00adf2; font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;color:#fff; text-align: center;">
                Faceate volorunt uta quo moditas
                <br> et labo. Comnima iorehent hit est
                <br> am vit elit volores cimpossime
                <br> serchit, oditiis rehenis volor
                <br> sequisqui ut late cus. Faceate
                <br> volorunt uta quo moditas et labo.
                <br> Comnima ioreh.
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <!--ROW 3 LINE -->
              <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;padding: 22px;background-color:#00adf2;vertical-align:top;">
                <!-- NESTED TABLE -->
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width: 100%;" width="100%">
                        <!-- TABLE FOR LINE -->
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" bgcolor="#fff" height="3" style="height:4px;width:50px;font-size:0px;" width="50"></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <td style="padding-bottom:18px;"></td>
                        <!-- TABLE FOR LINE END -->
                      </td>
                      <!-- LINE END -->
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <!-- NESTED TABLE END -->
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <!-- FIRST ROW CLOSE -->
    </tr>
    <!------------->
    <!-- IMAGE 3 -->
    <!------------->
    <tr>
      <!------------->
      <td align="right" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;padding-left:20px; max-height: 286px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="height:288px; max-width:332px;" valign="top">
          <tbody>
            <!--ROW 2 IMAGE -->
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="font-family:'Arial',Helvetica,sans-serif; background-color:#282929; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; padding-top:30px;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!--ROW 2 TEXT -->
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="background-color:#282929; font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;color:#fff; text-align: center;">
                Faceate volorunt uta quo moditas
                <br> et labo. Comnima iorehent hit est
                <br> am vit elit volores cimpossime
                <br> serchit, oditiis rehenis volor
                <br> sequisqui ut late cus.
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <!--ROW 3 LINE -->
              <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;padding: 22px;background-color:#282929;vertical-align:top; min-height: 286px;">
                <!-- NESTED TABLE -->
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width: 100%;" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" bgcolor="#282929" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; border-radius:5px; background-color:#282929; width:137px;height:42px;">
                            <a href="#" style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif; color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; padding:10px 0; border-radius:5px;
                background-color:transparent; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; line-height:20px; text-transform:uppercase; letter-spacing: 1px; width:137px; 
                border: 2px solid #fff;" target="_blank">
                   Read more
                </a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>

                        <td style="padding-bottom:17px;"></td>
                        <!-- TABLE FOR LINE END -->
                      </td>
                      <!-- LINE END -->
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <!-- NESTED TABLE END -->
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <!------------->
      <!-- IMAGE 4 -->
      <td align="left" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;;padding-right:20px; max-height: 286px; max-width:332px;" valign="bottom">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <!-- IMAGE -->
              <td align="left" style="font-family:'Arial',Helvetica,sans-serif;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img alt="Image-2" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/img.png" style="display:block;border:0px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#ffffff;" height="286">
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <!-------->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The gap is in column 2, why is this happening?

Comment: please don't use tables for layout.

Comment: It's for a HTML 5 email.

Comment: Padding and actual width of images - you have a padding-right of 20px

Comment: Yeah, my bad, maybe I wasn't clear enough, the gap is between the td with the blue background and the image of the woman in the field.

Comment: @Freddy if it's for an email, it's probably worth adding that to the question, otherwise you might invite answers that use techniques you can't rely on in email clients (such as `position` or `transform`).

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the image `height` which you specified as `286`. But the table on the left side have height of `288px`. Make image also `288`

Answer (score 0):

One work around could be to give the Image-2 (woman in the field) the following css to shift it up. I checked the image by itself and it doesn't seem to have any weird invisible black line. And I tried turning off all the padding on the parent td element. This is not ideal but does achieve visually what you are looking for.

```
position: relative;
top: -2px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really the solution to your table layout problem, but rather *how to do it without tables*.

[See on Codepen](https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/eybjOQ?editors=1100)

```css
.layout {
  width: 692px;
  background: #2c2d2d;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.layout .row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.layout .row>div {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  height: 286px;
  padding: 0 30px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  text-align: center;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.layout .row>div.bg-blue {
  background: #00acf2;
}

.layout .row>div img.bigQuote {
  margin-top: -15px;
}

.layout .row>div p {
  margin: 0;
}

.layout .row>div span.caret {
  display: block;
  height: 5px;
  width: 30px;
  background: #fff;
}

.layout .row>div span.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: #fff solid 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left" style="background-image:url(https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/image-1.png);"></div>
    <div class="right bg-blue"><img class="bigQuote" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/speech.png" />
      <p>Faceate volorunt uta quo moditas et labo. Comnima iorehent hit est am vit elit volores cimpossime serchit, oditiis rehenis volor sequisqui ut late cus. Faceate volorunt uta quo moditas et labo. Comnima ioreh.</p><span class="caret"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <p>Faceate volorunt uta quo moditas et labo. Comnima iorehent hit est am vit elit volores cimpossime serchit, oditiis rehenis volor sequisqui ut late cus.</p><span class="button">Read more</span>
    </div>
    <div class="right" style="background-image:url(https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/img.png);"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He said it was for an email template which is understandable, not for a page layout. The OP failed to mention this in the question but added it in the comments.

Comment: Yes, I saw that after posting. I was busy re-creating the layout -_-

Answer (score 0):

Change `height` to 286px for the table inside the `td`following the `<!-- IMAGE 3 -->` comment, and change `valign` to `top` in the last table (which contains the image and follows after the `<!-- IMAGE 4 -->` comment line )

```html
<table bgcolor="#0a1219" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="max-width:692px;background-color:#0a1219;" width="692">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!------------->
      <!-- IMAGE 1 -->
      <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;;padding-left:20px; max-height: 286px; max-width:332px;" valign="bottom">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <!-- IMAGE -->
              <td align="right" style="font-family:'Arial',Helvetica,sans-serif;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img alt="Image-1" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/image-1.png" style="display:block;border:0px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#ffffff" height="286">
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <!------------->
      <!-- IMAGE 2 -->
      <td align="left" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;padding-right:20px; max-height: 286px; max-width:332px;" valign="bottom">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <!--ROW 1 IMAGE -->
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; background-color:#00adf2;">

                <img alt="Speech marks" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/speech.png" style="display:block;border:0px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#ffffff; padding-top: 3px;" width="310">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!--ROW 1 TEXT -->
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="background-color:#00adf2; font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;color:#fff; text-align: center;">
                Faceate volorunt uta quo moditas
                <br> et labo. Comnima iorehent hit est
                <br> am vit elit volores cimpossime
                <br> serchit, oditiis rehenis volor
                <br> sequisqui ut late cus. Faceate
                <br> volorunt uta quo moditas et labo.
                <br> Comnima ioreh.
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <!--ROW 3 LINE -->
              <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;padding: 22px;background-color:#00adf2;vertical-align:top;">
                <!-- NESTED TABLE -->
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width: 100%;" width="100%">
                        <!-- TABLE FOR LINE -->
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td align="center" bgcolor="#fff" height="3" style="height:4px;width:50px;font-size:0px;" width="50"></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <td style="padding-bottom:18px;"></td>
                        <!-- TABLE FOR LINE END -->
                      </td>
                      <!-- LINE END -->
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <!-- NESTED TABLE END -->
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <!-- FIRST ROW CLOSE -->
    </tr>
    <!------------->
    <!-- IMAGE 3 -->
    <!------------->
    <tr>
      <!------------->
      <td align="right" style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;padding-left:20px; max-height: 286px;">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="height:286px; max-width:332px;" valign="top">
          <tbody>
            <!--ROW 2 IMAGE -->
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="font-family:'Arial',Helvetica,sans-serif; background-color:#282929; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; color: #fff; padding-top:30px;">
              </td>
            </tr>
            <!--ROW 2 TEXT -->
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="background-color:#282929; font-family:Arial;font-size:14px;line-height:20px;color:#fff; text-align: center;">
                Faceate volorunt uta quo moditas
                <br> et labo. Comnima iorehent hit est
                <br> am vit elit volores cimpossime
                <br> serchit, oditiis rehenis volor
                <br> sequisqui ut late cus.
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <!--ROW 3 LINE -->
              <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;padding: 22px;background-color:#282929;vertical-align:top; min-height: 286px;">
                <!-- NESTED TABLE -->
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td align="center" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width: 100%;" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                          <td align="center" bgcolor="#282929" style="font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; border-radius:5px; background-color:#282929; width:137px;height:42px;">
                            <a href="#" style="font-family:Arial,sans-serif; color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none; display:inline-block; padding:10px 0; border-radius:5px;
                background-color:transparent; font-size:14px; font-weight:bold; text-align:center; line-height:20px; text-transform:uppercase; letter-spacing: 1px; width:137px; 
                border: 2px solid #fff;" target="_blank">
                   Read more
                </a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>

                        <td style="padding-bottom:17px;"></td>
                        <!-- TABLE FOR LINE END -->
                      </td>
                      <!-- LINE END -->
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <!-- NESTED TABLE END -->
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <!------------->
      <!-- IMAGE 4 -->
      <td align="left" style="font-family:'Open Sans',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;;padding-right:20px; max-height: 286px; max-width:332px;" valign="top">
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <!-- IMAGE -->
              <td align="left" style="font-family:'Arial',Helvetica,sans-serif;">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                  <img alt="Image-2" src="https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/3055391/Inbound/CPD%202017/Email/Newsletter%20%20-%20Customers/img.png" style="display:block;border:0px;font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;color:#ffffff;" height="286">
                </a>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
      <!-------->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

P.S.: Try not to use inline styles, it's extremely tedious to work with.